# How to secure ubuntu desktop after a hack?

Tags: windows, linux

I have two ubuntu laptops that were recently compromised. I understand that it's probably a fruitless endeavor to try to find the hacker. I want to know how to secure my ubuntu desktop so that the hacker is kept out in the future. I'd also like to know how to secure my computer against a man in the middle attack on ubuntu and windows.

Comment: "Secure a Ubuntu desktop" is an exceptionally broad topic.  You should probably try to narrow things down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark says it's an extremely broad topic. People have written entire 500 page [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590594444) on the subject. However the best advice for someone after a breach is:

1. Backup all your data and re-install. Do not try to simply clean your system. Root kits can hide very well and you don't want to miss one.
2. When you do re-install change all your passwords (in case of key loggers etc...) and pick secure ones.[1]
3. Make sure you keep your software up to date. New vulnerabilities are found all the time and it's important to patch.

Because it's a laptop the other thing I'd add is if someone has physical access then they can do pretty anything unless it's encrypted and even then if it's already switched on and decrypted, encryption may not help much.

[1] I personally like [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/) style passwords and a [password safe](http://keepass.info/) but what the best practice with passwords is could start a holy war.

Comment: That Apress Linux Hardening book you link to is interesting, however it's from 2005. In the past nine years so many things have changed...

Answer (score 1):

- Install and configure UFW, the firewall. I believe it's not on by default. It's quite easy to configure.
- Use a virus scanner: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus
- Secure and check your home network. Rootkits and viruses can hide on other computers, devices and even digital tv recorders nowadays. You can clean your laptop and be infected again if the rootkit is in the same network.
- Use OpenDNS or Google DNS to prevent DNS hijacking.
- Make backups of your data and preferably have two different backup methods, one offsite.
- Follow @Hybrid's advice as well.
- Use a password manager like lastpass or keepass, and if you don't trust lastpass, still use it for those forums that don't matter that much. (That could even be this forum - what harm will it do to you if you lost your login here aside from the annoyance?)
- Use different password tactics for your mail, your computer login, public fora, sites that can be trusted with your creditcard info like paypal or Amazon, etc. Write it out so you have it clear.
- Encrypt your home folder: it won't protect against a rootkit, but when you lose your laptop the data is safe. Be sure to have a backup!
- Avoid using free wifi points, and if you use them, try to use VPN.
- If you run services like ssh server, webserver with open ports to the outside world, use Fail2ban, Snort, monit, munin and other tools to get an idea what is happening.
- Reinstall on a more regular basis. Document the install process. Try to install via apt-get and copy all those commands in a document, so you can paste them when reinstalling. If you have a spare external drive, make an image of the freshly installed harddisk.
- Keep your data on another partition, so you can reinstall without having to restore all data once you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you need to format the disk and reinstall the OS and save only the data where you are sure that they are not compromized.
Not only encrypt your home directory. Encrypt your whole disk / Filesystem.
It is quite easy to do so.
Maybe this link helps:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems

Comment: This doesn't help against a compromise on a system in use.  If the system is in use, the encryption keys are in memory and if the attacker can compromise the system, they then have access to the drives.  This stops neither threat that the OP is asking about.

Comment: "that the hacker is kept out in the future." So IMO you can assume that the system is clear now, but I will edit my answer

Comment: you still aren't understanding.  It doesn't matter if the attacker is out now.  If the computer is in use, then encryption doesn't keep an attacker out.  It just prevents accessing the system when it is not operating (which having the system turned off generally does a pretty good job too for remote attackers like this question is talking about).  Encryption is a mechanism to protect data theft at rest, not intrusion.

Comment: It does not state that the attack was remote, neither which attack it was and how the computer was compromized